# Threading: Thread Class object not taking a function with int [] return type

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I made this function to sort an array. I have to used in a threading example.

```
public int[] Arrsort()
{
    int[] array = new int[100];
    Random rand = new Random(12345);

     for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
     {
        array[i] = rand.Next(100);
     }
    Array.Sort(array);
    return array;
}
```

The problem with the function is that it wasn't working with Thread class object. As in when when I was passing it as follows-->

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(p.Arrsort);
    newThread.Start();
    int[] arrsort1 = p.Arrsort();
    // for (int n=0; n<arrsort.Length; n++)
    Console.WriteLine(arrsort1[n]); //printing the elements
}
```

The code was generating this error...

> Error CS0407  'int[] Program.Arrsort()' has the wrong return type

Therefore, I was compelled to make another function

```
public void Thrsort() { Arrsort(); } 
//void method created so Arrsort() can be called in thread
//the Thread class is not taking int[] types directly (please see)
```

I passed Thrsort () into the thread object. Then only my code was being compiled.

Is there any other way to solve the problem so that I have not to create another function i.e. thrsort()? Please suggest edits in code of function arrsort ()..

Comment: what are you trying to do? The function you pass to new thread must return void. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeh..the constructor will only be taking void type...actually i am asking how i can edit my function arrsort () code..so that i would not be using another function with return type.

Comment: and so your question is what

Comment: What is your goal? What do you want to gain?

Comment: make arrsort return void

Comment: I actually want only one function in the class.. As in there is only function  which is doing all the job and then also have a void return type so that it can be passed into the thread constructor,

Comment: Yes I did that..but then the function will not be returning anything.. I have to print the sorted array outside the function arrsort...how can i print it then?

Comment: We rarely use naked Threads anymore. Mostly we have Task[T]. Those can then be executed via Cooperative Multitasking, Threadpools or any other number of ways. Two special things to mind when doing sorting: 1. Make certain you sort a copy of the list. You do not want to have other code writing the array while your code is sorting it. 2. Sorting routines are highly optimised and rarely CPU bound. As such running them in a extra thread will likely not be beneficial. For both reasons adding Multithreading to this sorting might not be the best idea.

Comment: `Thread newThread = new Thread(() => p.Arrsort());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this function to sort an array. I have to used in a threading example.

```cs
public int[] Arrsort()
{
    int[] array = new int[100];
    Random rand = new Random(12345);

     for (int i = 0; i <100; i++)
     {
        array[i] = rand.Next(100);
     }
    Array.Sort(array);
    return array;
}
```

The code was generating this error...

> Error CS0407 'int[] Program.Arrsort()' has the wrong return type

The problem with the function is that it wasn't working with Thread class object. As in when I was passing it as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(p.Arrsort);
    newThread.Start();
    int[] arrsort1 = p.Arrsort();
    // for (int n=0; n<arrsort.Length; n++)
    Console.WriteLine(arrsort1[n]); //printing the elements
}
```

When you start a thread, it'll begin running in parallel. You don't quite know when it is going to finish. 
That is why you can't just read the function's return value-- it could very well still be running! 
That is why all thread procedures return void.

Comment: thank you for the explanation..I knew that but i wanted to change my code such that i don't need the function thrsort. My problem was well understood by @john wu

Answer (score 0):

When you start a thread, it'll begin running in parallel. You don't quite know when it is going to finish. That is why you can't just read the function's return value-- it could very well still be running! That is why all thread procs return void.

There are a couple thing you could do to get data back out. One is to set an agreed variable upon its completion, e.g.

```
int[] buffer = null;

public void Arrsort()
{
    /* snip */
    Array.Sort(array);
    buffer = array;
}
```

Then to read it:

```
if (!newThread.IsAlive)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Thread has finished and the output is as follows:");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", buffer));
}
```

That is sort of a brute force way to do it, and a little risky-- if you try to read the array while it is still being written you could be in for some serious problems. There are far safer ways.

One "better" way is to use a Task.Run to put it on the thread pool, then await it.

```
public int[] Arrsort()
{
    /* snip */
    Array.Sort(array);
    return array;
}
```

Then run it with [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx), which will put it on the thread pool:

```
    var task = Task.Run( () => Arrsort() );
    var result = task.Result;  //Will block until result is available
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation..I was actually looking for something like this.

Comment: @HamzaQureshi: It would be even better to `await` the task rather than fetching the result directly. Though the technique given here works, it is nonsensical; you are freezing one thread while another works!  Why would you hire a second worker and make the first worker idle until the second worker was done working?

Comment: @Eric. I'd have used await but I don't think the containing method is async, so that wouldn't compile. As for why would you would want a second worker, I think that is outside the scope of the question; I am treating the code example as just that, under the assumption that the real code would involve additional stuff to be run in parallel. But I can only guess, and agree with the spirit of your comment.